# why i cant remove last element after removing elements before it

Tags: javascript

There are 6 li elements each with a remove button as child Node removing the li when clicked

But when i delete a li element after deleting its sibling (before it in position and deletion) then console show following error :"TypeError: cannot read property of undefined 'parentNode' of undefined" .

I have started learning js but i dont understand this error
as normally the position also should change as it happens in array or vectors when we delete a middle element

Example.  if i delete 3rd element and then try to delete 4th element(that was just after the 3rd element) then this error ocurs and the li is also not deleted

```
let removeli=document.getElementsByClassName('remove');
for(let i=0;i<upperli.length;i++){
       removeli[i].addEventListener('click',()=>{
              //parent node pn i.e. li
              let pn = removeli[i].parentNode;
              //parent node of pn  i.e. ul thats why ulpn
              let ulpn = pn.parentNode;
              ulpn.removeChild(pn);
       })
}
```

Comment: To simplify your code, experiment with console.logs inside your loop first. Just to note, it is bad practice to addEventListener on lots of lis. Better to add it to the parent, and catch the click via propagation.

Comment: `.getElementsByClassName()` returns a _live_ `HTMLCollection`. Removing an element from the DOM will automatically update the content of `removeli`. Either use `.querySelectorAll()` to get the elements (which returns a non-live `NodeList`), or use `this` with a "normal" `function() { }` instead of `removeli[i]` in the event handler.

Comment: If you changed it to a normal `function(){}` then you could use `this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode)` and remove the indexing all together.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your event listener is forming a closure position in the list that gets passed directly into the event handler function.  In other words, when you call `ulpn.removeChild(pn)`, the value of `i` is not changing.  If you were to *re-query the DOM*, you'd find the positions have shifted, but you are storing your own positions in `removeli` and `upperli` as `i`.

Try something like this:

```
let removeLi = document.getElementsByClassName('remove');
for (let i = 0; i < removeLi.length; i++) {
    removeLi[i].addEventListener('click', ((pn) => {
        //parent node of pn  i.e. ul thats why ulpn
        let ulpn = pn.parentNode;
        ulpn.removeChild(pn);
    })(removeLi[i].parentNode));
}
```

The key is that the event listener function no longer depends on `i`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/) instead of working with live HTMLCollection,  so you can listen clicks also for elements added dinamically; test the "Add item" button.

```js
// Listen clicks on the parent
let ul = document.querySelector('ul');
ul.addEventListener('click', e => {
    // Was a button with "remove" class clicked?
    if(e.target.classList.contains('remove')) {
        // Get parent LI and remove it directly
        e.target.closest('li').remove();
    }
    // If you have edit buttons, you can manage those clicks here
    if(e.target.classList.contains('edit')) {
        // Do your stuff here
    }
});
// Add new element
document.querySelector('#add').addEventListener('click', () => {
    // This is just an example
    ul.innerHTML += '<li>New element <button class="remove">Remove</button></li>';
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1 <button class="remove">Remove</button></li>
  <li>Item 2 <button class="remove">Remove</button></li>
  <li>Item 3 <button class="remove">Remove</button></li>
  <li>Item 4 <button class="remove">Remove</button></li>
  <li>Item 5 <button class="remove">Remove</button></li>
</ul>
<button id="add">Add item</button>
```